the token is not being validated to return information
The /login route gives me the token, but when I go to the /userinfo route and send the token it gives me an invalid token

def auth():
    cursor = conexao.cursor()
    if verifica():
        token = jwt.encode({
            'nome': request.json['username'],
            'exp': str(datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=120))
        }, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm="HS256")
        cursor.close()
        return jsonify({'token': token})
    else:
        cursor.close()
        return make_response('Credenciais inválidas', 403)


def verifica():
    nome = request.json['username']
    senha = request.json['password_hash']
    cursor = conexao.cursor()
    comando = f'SELECT username, password_hash FROM users WHERE username = "{nome}"'
    cursor.execute(comando)
    resultado = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in resultado:
        username, hashed_senha = row
        if descripto(senha, hashed_senha.encode('utf-8')):
            cursor.close()
            return True
    cursor.close()
    return False

def token_request(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'Alerta': 'Token não recebido'}), 403
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=["HS256"])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return jsonify({'Alerta': 'Token expirado'}), 403
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return jsonify({'Alerta': 'Token inválido'}), 403
        return func(payload, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated



@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_auth():
    cursor = conexao.cursor()
    if verifica():
        token = jwt.encode({
            'nome': request.json['username'],
            'exp': str(datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=120))
        }, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm="HS256")
        cursor.close()
        return jsonify({'token': token})
    else:
        cursor.close()
        return make_response('Impossível verificar', 403)


@app.route('/userinfo', methods=['GET'])
@token_request
def user_info(payload):
    username = payload['nome']
    cursor = conexao.cursor()
    comando = f'SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = "{username}"'
    cursor.execute(comando)
    resultado = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    if resultado:
        username, email = resultado
        return jsonify({"username": username, "email": email}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "Usuário não encontrado"}), 404


The /login route gives me the token, but when I go to the /userinfo route and send the token, it gives me an invalid token and so I can't access the user's information. Here is the code with the login routes that return a token when sending a username and password, and the authentication route that returns the user's personal information when sending the token. I can receive the token from the login route, but I can't authenticate it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
